# Fedex rails gem/plugin documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedex

I'm working on a existing rails project built using rails 2.3, they have a used a fedex plugin for their shipping. The plugin is

```
  "git://github.com/kdonovan/fedex.git"
```

This plugin is working fine till now for shipping which is not international, but I have been given an task to implement international shipping for the existing project. The problem i'm facing is not able to find any sort of documentation for this plugin. Can any one point me the direction where to find the documentation for international shipping.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't much documentation in the gem. You can build your local documentation for a particular gem repository with

```
git clone https://github.com/kdonovan/fedex.git
cd fedex
rdoc
```

then point your browser to `doc/index.html`. The most interesting parts here seem to be the `README` and the documentation for `Fedex::Base`.

Comment: but even then there is not much mentioned about international shipping.

Comment: Then you've asked the wrong question I guess :) Your question was "Can any one point me the direction where to find the documentation?". I don't know the Gem so I can't help with international shipping, sorry.

Comment: sorry had to have mentioned for international shipping, thanks anyways.